# Is it semantically valid to put an aside tag inside a header tag?

Tags: html

As in:

```
<header id="mainHeader">
        <hgroup>
               <h1>Title</h1>
               <h2>Sub Title</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <aside>
                <p>Some content within the header but isn't as important.</p>
                <p>Some content within the header but isn't as important line 2.</p>
            </aside>            
    </header>
```

The reason for this, as demonstrated above, is that I have some content that belongs to the header (for instance, a short block of information) but is only somehow related but not really as essential as the h1 and h2 tags.

Or should I just use a normal div?

Comment: "P" tags are also related and not so important as the h1, and h2, so that would semantically ok without the aside too, I guess. 

I'm not sure if you can or cannot put the aside like that, though.

Comment: Btw `hgroup` is already obsolete now. http://www.webmonkey.com/2013/04/w3c-drops-hgroup-tag-from-html5-spec/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per HTML5 drafts, `<aside>` is content tangential to the main content, so this is not about importance but about topics. The `<aside>` element might contain shocking news, which are tangential to the boring content of a dull page.

What really matters is what other people who might look at your HTML markup think about it. The “semantics” of the new elements like `<header>` and `<aside>` [has recently been characterized](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2012-February/034835.html) (by Hixie, the HTML5 editor) as mostly relating to ease of authoring and maintenance.

If *you* are not sure of the “semantics” yourself, the odds are that others would have difficulties with it, too. So it might be safer to use just `<div class="foo">` where `foo` somehow characterizes the role of the content.

Comment: ...or a ```<section>```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, asides should relate to their parent element's content in a way that either highlights some content or does something to sum up or enhance the content.  Think of an aside as your content breaking the fourth wall.

In other words, yes to your question, but no to your example.  If you have a pull quote or an explanation that relates directly to the content in your header, by all means, use the aside element.  If you just have content that isn't as important as some of the other content, I'd say use `<section>` instead.

Comment: I agree with your answer, except for the "section" part. The spec said you shouldn't use sections instead of divs if you don't need to. Sections should only be used if you have a heading for it. In the original example,a simple div would be the best choice, in my opinion.